# Changing citation style in LyX from numeric to author-year

Tags: lyx

I'm trying to change the citation style from `numeric` to `author-year` but it somehow keeps both of them (Pyke et al. [4]). As you can see it doesn't show the year, only the ID number.
I tried to change the bibliography style to `plainnat` as was recommended here but it didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

**Example:**

```
#LyX 2.1 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 474
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass elsarticle
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_math auto
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize a4paper
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine natbib
\cite_engine_type authoryear
\biblio_style plainnat
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 2
\tocdepth 2
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Section

\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Many of those retailers soon realized what 
\begin_inset CommandInset citation
LatexCommand cite
key "Ricker(1999)"

\end_inset

wrote just couple of months before: "It is here - in the down and dirty
 details of consumer direct order fulfillment - that the epic battles for
 domination of the e-Commerce marketplace will ultimately be won or lost".

\series bold
\color red

\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset bibtex
LatexCommand bibtex
bibfiles "Bibliography"
options "plainnat"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

The bib entry is:

```
@Article{Ricker(1999),
  Title                    = {Order Fulfilment: The Hidden Key To E-Commerce Success},
  Author                   = {Fred R. Ricker and Ravi Kalakota},
  Journal                  = {Supply Chain Management Review},
  Year                     = {1999},
  Pages                    = {60-70},
  Volume                   = {Fall},

  Owner                    = {HP},
  Timestamp                = {2015.03.10}
}
```

Comment: Did you rerun `bibtex`?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't help :-(

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non)working example that we can play with?

Comment: Hey @Bernard, is it possible to upload the file here somehow?

Comment: @KatyaKopit For text files, just copy and paste them (there is a way to mark them as "code" so they have good formatting). Note that a .lyx file is just a text file (i.e. not binary). Don't worry if they're large (they should not be, remember this should be a *minimal* example), there will be scroll bars.

Comment: @scottkosty thanks! My shortest example (1 sentence) is too long to be copied in one comment. Is there something redundant there (so I can upload only the important part) or everything is important and I'll just divide it to 2 comments?

Comment: @KatyaKopit edit your question and put them there.

Comment: @KatyaKopit Did you try Tools -> Reconfigure and restart `lyx` to ensure the changes took effect?

Comment: @EngBIRD Yes. The problem doesn't solved after reconfiguration and restart.

Comment: @KatyaKopit Could you possibly add the bibliography file in comment mode to your question?  Or at least as much that would include your Riker1999 citation? At present (replacing your reference with one of my own) I am unable to reproduce your error.

Comment: @EngBIRD Added.

Comment: @KatyaKopit When I compile your MWE I get exactly the output I would expect.  Do you see the problematic mixed citation style depicted for ref 4 everywhere (including in your first sentence)?  If you don't see this mixed citation style until your 4th reference or so,  could you add more material and references to try and make this reproducible?